# How i can rewrite variable without changing address in memory?

Tags: swift, memory, struct, swift5

I have one class which contains `userEnterprise`

```
class API {

    static var sharedAPI = API()    

    var userEnterprise: Enterprise?

}
```

`Enterprise` contains `Survey` which contains `Block` like this

```
struct Enterprise {
   var surveys: [Survey]
}

struct Survey {
   var blocks: [Block]
}

struct Block {
   var blockStatus: BlockStatus
}
```

I need to change `blockStatus` from other class, but other class have info only about `Block` which it need to present

```
class blockPresenter(): UIViewController {
   var blockToPresent: Block

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if surveyBlock?.subBlocks![indexPath.row].blockStatus != .answered {
            apiManager.updateBlockStatus(where: surveyBlock!.subBlocks![indexPath.row], with: surveyId!, and: .watched)
        }
    }
}
```

In API i try to do this, but it doesn't work

```
func updateBlockStatus(where searchedBlock: Block, with surveyId: Int, and newStatus: BlockStatus) {
        for survey in userEnterprise!.surveys! {
            if survey.surveyId != surveyId { continue }
            if survey.firstBlock?.subBlocks?.count == 0 { return }
            renameLater(survey.firstBlock!.subBlocks!, searchedBlock, newStatus)
        }
    }

func renameLater(_ blocks: [Block], _ searchedBlock: Block, _ newStatus: BlockStatus) {
    for var block in blocks {
        if block == searchedBlock {
            block.setBlockStatus(newStatus: newStatus)
            print("->", block.blockName, block.blockStatus)
            return
        }
        if block.subBlocks == nil { continue }
        renameLater(block.subBlocks!, searchedBlock, newStatus)
    }
    return
}
```

How I can update `blockStatus` in `BlockStruct`?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to achieve this.

The naïve solution would be to make Block a class instead of a struct. A class is passed by reference instead of copied. So by doing this, a modification on the block in the controller will be reflected on the API.

However this is not a recommended solution as it introduces side effects and make your code hard to understand in the future. You models should remain as structs.

A good solution would be to add a function in your API class :

```
   func update(block: Block, surveyId: String) {
       // find the survey with the Id surveyId and update its block
   }
```

I suppose here your Survey struct has some kind of identifier so that you can find it amongst the other surveys of the enterprise.

Your controller should like this

```
class BlockViewController: UIViewController {
   let api: API

   let surveyId: String
   var block: Block

   // ....
}
```

EDIT : After you updated your question, I think I understand your problem better. When you write this line
`for var block in blocks` 
the block variable is a copy of the actual block you want to update. So this doesn't update your API.

Below is an example of what the API could look like. I took the liberty of using dictionaries instead of arrays as it's more convenient to update. The real key is here : `enterprise.surveys[surveyId]?.update(block: block)` because with the [...] notation ([subscript](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html)) we access in read-write the elements of the dictionary.

```swift
enum BlockStatus {
    case answered
    case notAnswered
}

struct Block {

    typealias Id = Int

    let id: Id
    var status: BlockStatus
}

struct Survey {

    typealias Id = Int

    let id: Id
    var blocks: [Block.Id: Block]

    mutating func update(block: Block) {
        blocks[block.id] = block
    }
}

struct Enterprise {
    var surveys: [Survey.Id: Survey]
}

struct API {
    var enterprise: Enterprise

    mutating func update(block: Block, surveyId: Survey.Id) {
        enterprise.surveys[surveyId]?.update(block: block)
    }

    func getBlock(id: Block.Id, inSurveyWithId surveyId: Survey.Id) -> Block? {
        enterprise.surveys[surveyId]?.blocks[id]
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to do this, but ```blockStatus``` anyway return ```nil```

Comment: @Madara2hor Could you edit your question with the update method code and the call in BlockViewController so that I can see what's wrong ?

Comment: Ok, I did. Check please